# Select Menu Discord JS | How can i use array in .addOptions?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to map an array inside `.addOptions`.

Basically, I would like to add a value `{ }` to `addOptions` by taking the values of an object or array.

Examples:

```js
let menu = new SelectMenuBuilder()
  .setCustomId('select')
  .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
  .addOptions(arrayt.map(song => label: song.name, description: song.formattedDuration, value: blabla)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of how your array look like

Comment: its like 
[
    {
      id: '8kcdvlgR1Uw',
      url: 'https://www.youbew',
     
    },
    {
      id: 'n61ULEU7CO0',
      name: 'Best of lofi ',

    }

]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing curly brackets in your `map` function. The function should look something like this

```
const songs = [
   {
     name: 'Song 1',
     formattedDuration: 2
   },
   {
     name: 'Song 2',
     formattedDuration: 5
   },
   {
     name: 'Song 3',
     formattedDuration: 6
   }
]

const menu = new SelectMenuBuilder()
      .setCustomId('select')
      .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
      .addOptions(songs.map(song => { return {label: song.name, description: song.formattedDuration }}))
```

Comment: Bro, My editor tells me to replace the commas with semicolons

Like this :    .addOptions(result.map(song => {   label: `${i1} . `+song.name.slice(0, 20); description: song.formattedDuration.replace(/00:00/g, "Live"); value: `${i1}`  }))

Comment: Error : TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'emoji' of 'selectMenuOption' as it is undefined.

I haven't coded anything about emoji though

Comment: I edited my code now it should work

Answer (score 0):

The values should be in the form of a string, not integer or double, whatever you are giving, use toString() on them.

```
const row = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents(
            new StringSelectMenuBuilder()
                .setCustomId('select')
                .setPlaceholder('Nothing selected')
                .addOptions(
                    adana.map(function (curentValue, index) {
                        return {
                            label: index.toString(),
                            value: index.toString(),
                        }
                    })
                )
        )
```